# NetCDFs with more than 4 dimensions in GeoServer

Tags: python, geoserver, geotools, netcdf

I have two very similar NetCDFs. "temp_4.nc", that I can load into GeoServer, and "temp_5_e.nc", that I can't. Both file have a single data variable "temp".  In the first one, it has dimensions (time, Z, lat, lon) and the second one has a dimension more (scen, time, Z, lat, lon).

I think my problem is that this extra dimension is not recognized by GeoServer. I tried adding attributes "axis: Z" and "units: m" (dim Z has the same attributes). As it didn't work, I also tried "axis: E" (ensemble) and no units.

When I try to create a store, I get the following error:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///geodata/temp_5_e.nc and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@42b74f33 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1bf473ef[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@702a025e STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true
```

And in the GeoServer log, I get a few miles of text. The full log is here : https://pastebin.com/2GZ4myYu.

```
11 Mar 21:24:15 WARN [imageio.netcdf] - Unsupported axis: long scen(scen=5);
  :axis = "E";
 in input: file:/geodata/temp_5_e.nc has been found
11 Mar 21:24:15 WARN [io.netcdf] - Unable to connect
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to connect
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFReader.<init>(NetCDFReader.java:158)
    at org.geotools.coverage.io.netcdf.NetCDFFormat.getReader(NetCDFFormat.java:94)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1571)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1516)
    [truncated output]
11 Mar 21:24:15 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:///geodata/temp_5_e.nc
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///geodata/temp_5_e.nc and hints Hints:
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@42b74f33                                                                                   
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1bf473ef[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
System defaults:
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@702a025e
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   

[truncated output]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:///geodata/temp_5_e.nc and hints Hints:
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@42b74f33                                                                                   
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1bf473ef[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
System defaults:
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@702a025e
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   

    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1573)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1516)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:129)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:98)
    ... 147 more
```

Anyone has any idea of what's going on?  How can I add 5D netCDf to geoserver?

I was guessing that the warning at the very top might be the reason for this error? How should I set this fifth coordinate so that geotools can understand it?

---

Below if the python code (with xarray) to generate the netcdf files:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.sample((5,5,5,5,5)),
    dims=('scen', 'time', 'Z', 'lat', 'lon'),
    coords={
        'time': xr.cftime_range('1900-01-01', freq='D', periods=5),
        'Z': xr.DataArray(np.arange(5), dims=('Z',), attrs={'axis': 'Z', 'units': 'm'}, name='Z'),
        'lat': xr.DataArray(np.arange(5), dims=('lat',), attrs={'axis': 'Y', 'units': 'degrees_north'}, name='lat'),
        'lon': xr.DataArray(np.arange(5), dims=('lon',), attrs={'axis': 'X', 'units': 'degrees_east'}, name='lon'),
        'scen': xr.DataArray(np.arange(5), dims=('scen',), attrs={'axis': 'E'}, name='scen')
    },
    name='temp'
).to_netcdf('temp_5_e.nc')
```

Comment the `'scen'` line and remove one `5` from the random data to get the (working) 4D case.

And the output of `ncdump` for each file:

```
# ncdump -sh temp_4.nc
netcdf temp_4 {
dimensions:
    time = 5 ;
    Z = 5 ;
    lat = 5 ;
    lon = 5 ;
variables:
    int64 time(time) ;
        time:units = "days since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000" ;
        time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
        time:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        time:_Endianness = "little" ;
    int64 Z(Z) ;
        Z:axis = "Z" ;
        Z:units = "m" ;
        Z:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        Z:_Endianness = "little" ;
    int64 lat(lat) ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        lat:_Endianness = "little" ;
    int64 lon(lon) ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        lon:_Endianness = "little" ;
    double temp(time, Z, lat, lon) ;
        temp:_FillValue = NaN ;
        temp:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        temp:_Endianness = "little" ;

// global attributes:
        :_NCProperties = "version=2,netcdf=4.7.4,hdf5=1.12.0," ;
        :_SuperblockVersion = 0 ;
        :_IsNetcdf4 = 1 ;
        :_Format = "netCDF-4" ;
}

# ncdump -sh temp_5_e.nc
netcdf temp_5_e {
dimensions:
    time = 5 ;
    Z = 5 ;
    lat = 5 ;
    lon = 5 ;
    scen = 5 ;
variables:
    int64 time(time) ;
        time:units = "days since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000" ;
        time:calendar = "gregorian" ;
        time:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        time:_Endianness = "little" ;
    int64 Z(Z) ;
        Z:axis = "Z" ;
        Z:units = "m" ;
        Z:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        Z:_Endianness = "little" ;
    int64 lat(lat) ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        lat:_Endianness = "little" ;
    int64 lon(lon) ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        lon:_Endianness = "little" ;
    int64 scen(scen) ;
        scen:axis = "E" ;
        scen:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        scen:_Endianness = "little" ;
    double temp(scen, time, Z, lat, lon) ;
        temp:_FillValue = NaN ;
        temp:_Storage = "contiguous" ;
        temp:_Endianness = "little" ;

// global attributes:
        :_NCProperties = "version=2,netcdf=4.7.4,hdf5=1.12.0," ;
        :_SuperblockVersion = 0 ;
        :_IsNetcdf4 = 1 ;
        :_Format = "netCDF-4" ;
}
```